# Testing if two finite sets of points differ only by rotation (unordered, in polynomial time in size and dimension)?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, graph-isomorphism, invariance

Imagine we have two size $m$ sets (without order) of points $X=\{x^i\}_{i=1..m}, Y=\{y^i\}_{i=1..m} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and we want to answer the question if they differ only by rotation: if there exists othogonal $O^TO=OO^T=I$ such that $X=\{Oy^i:i=1..m\}$.

It simple to test in exponential time, the question is if it be answered in polynomial time (in both $m$ and $n$)?

While it might seem simple, it isn't - the most difficult cases of graph isomorphism problem: for [strongly regular graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_regular_graph) (SRG) can be translated to above problem. We can **assume that all points are on a sphere**, for SRGs they form very regular high dimensional polyhedron (diagram below) having $m\approx 2n$ points.

Testing differing only by rotation is simple for symmetric matrices - they differ only by rotation if traces of all $n$ powers are equal ($\exists_O P=O^TQO \Leftrightarrow \forall_k \textrm{Tr}(P^k)=\textrm{Tr}(Q^k)$). Maybe we could use it for sets of points - by translating them into matrix e.g. $n\times n$:
$$P_{ab} = \sum_{i=1..m} x^i_a x^i_b\qquad Q_{ab} = \sum_{i=1..m} y^i_a y^i_b \qquad \forall_{k=1..n}\textrm{Tr}(P^k)=^?\textrm{Tr}(Q^k).$$ 
Above formula looks like eigendecomposition $(P=\sum_i \lambda_i v^i v^{iT})$ if vectors are orthogonal and $m\leq n$, but generally it does not determine the used sets of points: for SRGs we have $m\approx 2n$ and above matrices turn out proportional to identity matrix like for [POVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POVM)s.

One question is: **for how many points above test works?** (assume all have the same norm)

It trivially works for $m=1$ point, for two they can be opposite - zeroing the matrix, but it works otherwise (determining single angle), hence we need some independence assumption (?). Generally, for $m$ vectors spanning $n'$ dimensional subspace $(m\leq n'\leq n)$, they contain $m(n'-1)-n'(n'-1)/2=(m-n'/2)(n'-1)$ degrees of freedom modulo rotation, while above test uses $n$ degrees of freedom, from which all but $n'$ are trivial (zero eigenvalue). Hence we need $(m-n'/2)(n'-1)\leq n'$ condition. Is it sufficient?

We can also analogously use tests with higher order matrix (on tensor product) to increase the number of independent invariants, e.g. (corresponding to ladder-like graphs) $n^2 \times n^2$:

$$P_{ab,cd}=\sum_{ij} x^i_a x^i_c (x^i\cdot x^j) x^j_b x^j_d \qquad Q_{ab,cd}=\sum_{ij} y^i_a y^i_c (y^i\cdot y^j) y^j_b y^j_d$$
and testing if $\forall_{k=1..n^2 }\textrm{Tr}(P^k)=\textrm{Tr}(Q^k)$.

[I have recently checked](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z58uyz6otrs61t5/srginv.pdf) it for SRGs and it worked: distinguished all I have tested (up to 29 vertices). The question is **how to prove it: what maximal number of points (assuming some independence) it always distinguishes?** How this number changes with order of such method? Some example of third order:
$P_{abc,def}=\sum_{ijk} x^i_a x^i_d x^j_b x^j_e x^k_c x^k_f (x^i\cdot x^j) (x^i\cdot x^k)(x^j\cdot x^k)$.

Any other way to test it in polynomial time?

---

Example of two non-isomorphic $m=16$ vertex SRGs of the same parameters we would like to distinguish (for any vertex permutation). Eigenspectrums of their adjacency matrices are highly degenerated - taking orthonomal basis of $n=6$ dimensional eigenspace, treating its columns(!) as vectors, they form very regular polyhedron: scalar products recreate neighborhood relation: has one value for all neighbors, second for all non-neighbors, like in schematic diagram on the right:

[image]

---

**Update** (2018-09-21): interesting comment from https://redd.it/9hdwnl : any graph isomorphism problem can be translated to above by putting points in basis $\{e_i\}$ and $\{e_i + e_j \textrm{ for each edge }(i,j)\}$. This construction restricts rotations to permutations. Hence, solving the above problem for $m\sim n^2$ would also solve graph isomorphism problem. For strongly regular graphs it suffice to do it for $m\sim 2n$.

**Update** (2018-09-22): there was pointed similarity to [orthogonal Procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem), which finds optimal rotation knowing which point should rotate to which. Here we don't know it - just have sets without order: there are $m!$ possibilities.

Comment: Are the points in correspondence ?

Comment: To test orthogonality of a matrix, just verify that $R^TR=I$.

Comment: The problem is general - just some two sets of the same size. Rotation/orthogonality is as you have written. The issue is that we don't know permutation: which point should rotate to which.

Comment: Mh, I don't like that. Even with $d$ points, there are $d!$ possible matchings.

Comment: Can't geometric moments be used to retrieve the rotation matrix ?

Comment: Exactly, many approaches lead to exponential cost, for example restricting to only directional orders: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2599332/number-of-directional-orders-for-n-points-in-mathbbrd Hence I am using global description: large number of rotation invariants - kind of generalized moments. The question is how to prove that they provide complete description: determine set modulo rotation. This way we would get polynomial algorithm for graph isomorphism problem.

Comment: When I see such problems I always wonder how you test floating point numbers for equality.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter, indeed there is generally a problem with real numbers. In many situations like for SRGs we can assume that they are algebraic numbers - allowing for exact computation, which cost should be included in complexity. Otherwise, if they are computable, we would need to show that cost of calculating distinguishing digit grows at most in polynomial way. Maybe let's assume that they are algebraic.

Comment: Can't you fit an n-dimensional ellipsoid (PCA) to each of your sets and see if they coincide up to a rotation?

Comment: @rych, it would work in simple cases, but not in the tough ones - where PCA (or the first P_ab matrix above) would say that there are spherically symmetric - while they have some complex asymmetric patterns on this sphere. However, the lower matrix (P_{ab,cd}) starts seeing this asymmetry in eigendecomposition for tough cases - the question is characterizing it: for how many points it provides a sufficient condition for differing only by rotation?